# increase numbers in sed output stream sequentially

Tags: sed

I have a small sed script which should print "animal king 1:" in front of the first "yellow lion" occurrence, "animal king 2:" in front of the second "yellow lion" and "animal king 3:" in front of the third "yellow lion" occurrence. Is it possible to achive this in sed?

Content of input file for sed and output can be seen here:

```
[user@T60 ~]$ cat animals.txt 
red cat
blue dog
yellow lion
brown tiger
black hippo
yellow lion
white zebra
yellow lion
[martint@martint ~]$ cat sed-test.sh 
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sed 's/\(.*lion\)/\
\
animal king 1:\
\
\1 /' < "animals.txt"
[user@T60 ~]$ ./sed-test.sh 
red cat
blue dog


animal king 1:

yellow lion 
brown tiger
black hippo


animal king 1:

yellow lion 
white zebra


animal king 1:

yellow lion 
[user@T60 ~]$
```

As you can see, "animal king" number is "1" in all three occurrences. Is there a way to increase this by one after each ".*lion" match in sed?

Comment: Use `awk` to do computation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -re '/^.*lion/!b;w lion_file' -e 'g;s/[0-9]9*$/\n&/;h;y/0123456789/1234567890/;G;s/^.*\n(.*)\n(.*)\n.*/\2\1/;s/^(0*)\n*$/1\1/;h;s/^.*/\n\nanimal king &:\n/;R /lion_file' file
```

It is a bit of a cheat because it uses a temporary file to hold the `lion` line.

Comment: amazing sed-fu! I'd recommend editing into multi-line script to understand what is happening. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 2):

Way more readable with awk:

```
awk '/lion/ {printf("\nanimal kingdom %d:\n\n", ++n)} 1' animals.txt
```